# How to resize /dev/root partition?

Tags: partitioning, disk, resize

I have just installed ubuntu desktop on a dedicated remote server but the disk seems to be full even though the server has a 1Tb disk?:

```
desktop@xxxx:/$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          9.8G  9.3G  4.0K 100% /
/dev/root       9.8G  9.3G  4.0K 100% /
/dev            994M  8.0K  994M   1% /dev
none            199M  2.7M  197M   2% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            995M   12K  995M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2       921G   14G  862G   2% /home
```

I don't know what data I sould move to the /home folder or how to modify partitions to have some space?? The server is extremely slow and I can hardly connect to it through SSH :-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you choose this IMO bizarre partitioning scheme?

Comment: I selected the default proposed during the remote install... you reckon I will have to reinstall the whole thing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could try  `du -h / --max-depth=1` to see where your space is going. By the looks of it you used LVM ???  If so then it's easy. If not then it's hard.

If you are using one physical disk then you will have to shrink the `/home` partition first to give you some disk space you can use to make the root partition bigger.  You will also have to do this from a Live CD as your root partition can not be mounted when you resize it.

> - Unmount both the `/` and `/home` partitions
> - Shrink the `/home` partition file system
> - Shrink the `/home` partition logical volume
> - Increase the `/` partition logical volume
> - Increase the `/` partition file system

You will need to read up on LVM management commands as I can't remember those off the top of my head. You should make a back up first as you are playing with the root partition and you can easily wreck your system and make it unbootable.

First check if any log files have gone crazy and you can easily get some space back which should make things go a bit quicker.

Or the Live CD might have `gparted` installed already under tools so you could use that  for a graphical way.

Comment: Haven't used LVM :-/ Thanks for your answer Captain T